# Is there a way to set jvmArgs for Android Instrumented Tests in Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, instrumentation

I'd need to execute a JavaAgent when tests are running on an Android project.

I achieved to add jvmArgs for Android Unit Tests with the following configuration

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    ...
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            all {
                jvmArgs '-javaagent:/foo/bar/Agent.jar'
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
...
```

Is there any way to do the same for Android Instrumented Tests?